# Merging legends when plotting larger points lighter and smaller points darker in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have trolled `ggplot2` documentation, Stack and the `ggplot2` Google groups email list - but to no avail.

Please can someone tell me how to merge the legends for `alpha` (opacity) and `size`? They are titled "(1-val2)" and "val2", respectively.

Normally mapping alpha and size to val2 would automatically merge the axes. However because I'm using "val2" and "1-val2", this does not happen. I have played around with `scale_size_continuous` and `scale_alpha_continuous`, but didn't manage to come right.

Here is a MWE:

```
require(ggplot2)

dummy <- data.frame(x=c(runif(12,5,10)),
                y=c(runif(12,5,10)),
                val1=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                val2=c(0.4,0.6,0.7,0.2,0.8,0.6,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.4,0.7))

p <- ggplot() +
geom_point(data=dummy, aes(x=x, y=y,color=val1, size=val2, alpha=(1-val2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `range` argument of `scale_alpha_continuous` to invert the scale:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=dummy, aes(x=x, y=y,color=val1, size=val2, alpha=val2)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(1, 0.1))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 2):

The `trans` argument may also be useful here:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=dummy, aes(x = x, y = y, color = val1, size = val2, alpha = val2)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```

[image]

The description of the `trans` argument in `?scale_alpha_continuous` and `?continuous_scale` is pretty thin. However, you can find some examples [**here**](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/alpha).